# Apache Mod_Proxy Remote Negative Content-Length Buffer Overflow Vulnerability

Tags: vulnerability, apache, mod-security, tomcat

We have a Windows Server 2012 R2 running Apache 2.2.27 and Apache tomcat8 version 1.0.15.0.

Can you guys shed a few words on what the vulnerability is and also how to re-mediate this with the two versions that we are running in our environment.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you referring to [CVE-2004-0492](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=can-2004-0492) *"mod_proxy in Apache 1.3.25 to 1.3.31 ... possibly execute arbitrary code via a negative Content-Length HTTP header field..."* . As you can see, this bug did affect apache version 1.3.25 ... 1.3.31 but not your version 2.2.27.

Comment: what about the apache tomcat that i am running? Apache tomcat8 version 1.0.15.0, could the scan picked it up because of this?

Comment: @gsb005: Apache tomcat is unrelated to the Apache web server (where the vulnerability was) and thus is not affected. There are actually lots of Apache projects outside the web server, see https://projects.apache.org/projects.html?category.